# react-native can not run RNTester

Tags: node.js, react-native, babeljs

When I run the ./scripts/packager.sh the following error occurred:

```
/Users/zq/Repos/ReactNative/react-native/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:139
throw e;

Error: [BABEL] /Users/zq/Repos/ReactNative/react-native/local-cli/cliEntry.js: .default is not a valid Plugin property
at /Users/zq/Repos/ReactNative/react-native/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/plugins.js:54:56
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at validatePluginObject (/Users/zq/Repos/ReactNative/react-native/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/validation/plugins.js:52:20)
at /Users/zq/Repos/ReactNative/react-native/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:215:53
at cachedFunction (/Users/zq/Repos/ReactNative/react-native/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js:42:17)
at loadPluginDescriptor (/Users/zq/Repos/ReactNative/react-native/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:207:10)
at /Users/zq/Repos/ReactNative/react-native/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:64:16
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at recurseDescriptors (/Users/zq/Repos/ReactNative/react-native/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:63:36)
at loadFullConfig (/Users/zq/Repos/ReactNative/react-native/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:112:6)
```

ps: 
node v8.11.1

I try delete node_modules and reinstall

not working!